# How can I programatically modify an XML Document to respect a DTD in java

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML Document built programatically and waiting for serialisation (as a `String`). Before serialising it though, I would like to re-arrange its nodes so that they match the definition of the DTD. I should mention that my implementation prevents me to know in which order the tree will be built.

Any recommended solutions for this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is some academic research to correct invalid XML:

> [Correction of Invalid XML Documents with Respect to Single Type Tree
> Grammars](http://www.ksi.mff.cuni.cz/%7Esvoboda/research/papers/2011-corrector-ndt-2011-04-04.pdf)

but I don't know if there is any available library for that.

So you need to do it by hand, or better rework the generation of the document so that it produces a valid instance in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for this, will go through it. As to answer the rework of the generation. It is actually impossible since the input used to generate the document are received in a non deterministic order.